# WCF Service Hosted on IIS10. Can browse the .svc file but the wsdl does not show up

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, wsdl

I have a test WCF service that I hosted on IIS. I added a new application to the default website and used default app pool to host my test service. 
I am able to browse the .svc file from the content view in IIS and the success page along with a link to wsdl opens up on Windows IE. However, on clicking the wsdl link, a HTTP 404(Not found) error is thrown.(everything is on my localhost being accessed internally)
I have added the metadata endpoint and this is the relevant portion of my web.config file.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour" name="ClassLibrary1.HelloWorldService">
            <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="ClassLibrary1.IHelloWorldService" />
           <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:17000"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone please guide me about what I can be missing? Could it be a permissions issue or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the base address to service contract which will be provided by the IIS web server.
The default wcf application configuration enable the service metadata and we are able to access the metadata by the svc page or we directly use the following url.

> http://localhost:90/Service1.svc?wsdl

Feel free to contract me If the problem still exists.